# Calling SaveChanges once per request in Asp.Net MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection, transactions

I'm trying to create a mostly simple web app with Asp.Net MVC and Entity Framework. I actually finished few projects with it but wasn't satisfied about the code so I'm following some more popular ways to do it. Here is my structure:

- Controller gets the request,
- I have services which contain business logic. They also use my Database Context to change the data on the database. I didn't want to create another database layer so I'm using them,
- I inject my services to controller (with Unity) and call stuff like `CustomerService.Delete(Id)`
- My service deletes the data based on Id.

So my controller does not include any logic or database operations, my services does include both. I think it's a good way to do stuff but I have a problem.

Let's say I add a customer for the first time and there is another table keeping their balance and I want to include a bonus $10 for first registration, when I call my `CustomerService.Add(Customer)`, that method also calls `CustomerService.AddBalance(Customer, 10)`. In those methods I call `DbContext.SaveChanges`, here is the problem, I call `SaveChanges` 2 times, and if `CustomerService.AddBalance(Customer, 10)` fails for some reason I will still have the customer data but not the balance one. I know I can use a transactions but where do I put that code? If I knew there was a place which runs last before request is finished, I could call `SaveChanges()` there and it would work but I think that's not a great idea either.

Basically I want to call `SaveChanges()` once per request but I couldn't find a good place to do it.

Thanks

Comment: You can add to both tables at once and call SaveChanges once. It should work

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing any work with the database you want to be using transactions.  If you don't you are going to leave your db in an inconsistent state if one of your calls fails.  Using transactions, nothing will be committed in the database until you call Commit.  You can call SaveChanges as much a you like and it won't make a difference.

You can create a TransactionScope in a attribute and then add it to any controller action where you are accessing the db. Here' one I use

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class TransactionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private TransactionScope TransactionScope { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext filterContext)
    {
        TransactionScope =
            new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions
            {
                IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted
            });
    }
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (TransactionScope == null)
            return;

        if (filterContext.Exception == null)
        {
            TransactionScope.Complete();
            return;
        }

        TransactionScope.Dispose();
    }
}
```

You could put the transaction code in BeginRequest stash it in HttpContext and commit on EndRequest.  This is going to create a TransactionScope for every call that asp.net handles.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation EF by default sets all the changes to database in transaction until `SaveChanges()` is called. 
So you can extract the logic of adding to database to separate methods, create separate method which saves changes to DB and design your code as following:

- `AddCustomer` to DB (do not call save changes)
- `AddBalance` to DB(do not call save changes)
- `SaveChanges` on the end of the in your service method

This will guarantee that all happens in transaction and in case of any error changes to database won't be applied.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that creating an Extension to your Context (i am assuming your are using EF) is a good way to go:

```
public static class TIContextCompleteExtention
{
    public static void Complete(this TIContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public static async Task CompleteAsync(this TIContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

The Above TIConext is derived from EF's dbContext.

Wherever you need to COMPLETE your transaction use

_context.Complete(); or _context.CompleteAsync() instead of EF's SaveChanges() / SaveChangesAsync()

If you later swap out your ORM all you need to do is change the above extensions to fit your new Context.

Hope this helps.